# Disposing IDisposable items generated by Observable

Tags: idisposable, system.reactive

I have an `Observable<WebResponse>` (`WebResponse` implements `IDisposable`)

```
responseObservable
    .Where(webResponse => webResponse.ContentType.StartsWith("text/html"))
    .Select(webResponse => webResponse.ContentLength)
    .Run()
```

(Ignore the pointlessness of the query!)

so, I'm discarding `WebResponse` instances without calling `Dispose` on them. This seems bad.

More abstractly: If I have an `Observable<IDisposable>`, how do I deal with the disposal of generated items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a method `WebResponse CreateMyWebResponse()` use `Observable.Using` like this:

```
var responseObservable = Observable.Using(() => CreateMyWebResponse(), Observable.Return);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Where` and `Do` bits to something like

```
.Do(webResponse => {
    if (webResponse.ContentType.StartsWith("text/html")) 
        ProcessAndDispose(webResponse);
    else
        webResponse.Dispose(); })
```

perhaps?

EDIT

Based on your edit, how about

```
.Select(webResponse => {
    int r = -1;
    if (webResponse.ContentType.StartsWith("text/html")) 
        r = webResponse.ContentLength;
    webResponse.Dispose(); 
    return r; })
.Where(i => i != -1)
```

now?  This would generalize into something like

```
FilterProjectDispose(e, pred, proj) {
    e.Select(x => {
        using(x) {
            if (pred(x)) return Some(proj(x));
            else return None; }})
     .Where(x => x.IsSome)
     .Select(x => x.Value)
}
```

assuming `Some`/`None` as in F# (I am apparently starting to forget my C#).

Comment: I've edited my question slightly to reflect better what I'm actually doing. I'm really wondering if there's a pattern for dealing with this kind issue. I've looked at Observable.Using, but I don't really get it.